# How long should a medal ribbon be?

Tags: equipment, international-sports

I made some custom medals for some friends, who are running a race soon.

But I have doubts about how long I should make the ribbon.
Too short and it will be like a necklace, too long and it will go down to the waist.

I have never won a medal myself, so I have nothing to measure by and compare to.
(I have won trophies though, so don't feel sorry for me hehe.)

When I say length, I mean the length of the string (flat silk fabric) from end to end.
Since it's tied in one end forming a loop, I suppose you could also call it the circumference if you were to lay it out as a circle.

What is the common length? Or should I just estimate from how it hangs on myself, aiming for the upper part of the chest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The medal should support under the chest muscles, so normally the lenght should be around **60/70cm - (23/28 inches)**

Those elements normally are indipendent from the athlete's height because I think they are setted before knowing the order of arrival

The reply was base on the following images

[image: 01]

[image: 02]

[image: 03]